# Replace $(this) in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using Backbone to render a view on my homepage. In this view I have a view li elements containing movie titles (pure text). When I click on a li element I want to show it's content in my console.

I was using this,

```
events: -> 
  "click li": "showtext"

showtext: ->
  litext = $(this).text()
  console.log litext
```

In my head this should work. It should give me the text of the clicked li element. It does give me some feedback in the console but it's empty.

After reading [This](http://www.nathandavison.com/article/15/knowing-what-element-was-targeted-in-backbonejs-view-events) it became clear that `this` targets the view and not the element clicked. But I can't find out how to replace the `this` function.

How can I target a element from the view? So that when I click on a element it shows the text in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All click handlers are passed an `Event` object as their argument. This object has a `target` property, which is the object that has been clicked.

```
events:
  "click li": "showtext"

## @param {Event} event
showText: (event)->
  liText = $(e.target).text()
  console.log liText
```

#### Reference

[jQuery Event Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: I just did this `movietitle = $(event.currentTarget).text() console.log  movietitle` which also seems to work. But your code uses event.target instead of currentTarget, alright. By the way, if you define `event` and use just `e.target` you get a `ReferenceError: e is not defined ` error. Just a small thing.

Comment: There is an important difference between `target` and `currentTarget`, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/misteroneill/kmn4A/3/

Comment: `$(e.target).text` and `$(e.target).text()` are very different things, I'm pretty sure you want the latter in this case.